# USB 3 via ExpressCard/34 on a thunderbolt with parallels desktop

Tags: usb, virtualization, external-disk

Can I use an extenal  windows formatted USB3 harddisk on my mac connected via thunderbolt on the future Sonnet Echo-Expresscard/34-Thunderbolt-Adapter? It's clear I can use UBS3 HDs for Mac, but how is it when virtually running windows?

Answer (score 2):

If the drive works on the Mac side, it will work under Windows within the virtual environment.  The hardware is virtualized, so Windows will not see it as a USB3 device.

Comment: Thanks EmmEff. I'm asking because I don't see a single sentence in the huge Parallels Desktop@ database mentioning only once "USB 3". So  your answer means: it will be recognized, but only as USB 2?

Comment: Parallels Desktop (and all other virtualization apps for OS X) virtualize the standard interfaces (SATA, IDE, USB, etc).  None of them (currently) virtualize USB 3, but they all virtualize USB 2.

Comment: Parallels 8 supports USB3... Does it mean that a USB3 HD attached, will benefit from a USB2 port of my iMac? Can a USB2 port iMac give the speed of USB3 to a virtual machine? Mmmm.